# The value is not of type "System.Int32" and cannot be used in this generic collection

Tags: c#, json, odata

When using `HttpPatch` with `OData` I want to set `int[]` of access list to users. I am sending the `int[] ACL` (access list). The other fields from the RoleDto can be changed, however, the int[] cannot be changed. Let's say I have a role with access 1,2,3 and I want to change it to 2,3. If I do this using patch it throws an exception. It does not even hit the controller, it breaks in the middleware.

> The value is not of type "System.Int32" and cannot be used in this generic collection.

Here is the Controller Action.

```
    [ODataRoute("/api/v1/roles/")]
    [HttpPatch("{id}")]
    [ValidateModel]
    [ProducesResponseType(StatusCodes.Status400BadRequest)]
    [ProducesResponseType(StatusCodes.Status204NoContent)]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Patch([FromRoute] string id, [FromBody] Delta<RoleDto> patch)
    {
        var role = await roleManagerWrapper.FindRoleByIdAsync(id);

        if (role == null) throw new NotFoundException($"Role with id {id} was not found");

        var dto = mapper.Map<RoleDto>(role);

        patch.Patch(dto);

        mapper.Map(dto, role);

        AccessList.ValidateACLValues(dto.AccessLevel);

        await dbContext.SaveChangesAsync();

        return NoContent();
    }
```

Here is the RoleDto:

```
   [MapFrom(typeof(IntentRole))]
    public class RoleDto
    {
        public string Id { get; set; }

        public string Name { get; set; }

        public int UserCount { get; set; }

        [MaxLength(200)]
        public string Group { get; set; }

        public int[] AccessLevel { get; set; }
    }
```

Here is the IntentRole:

```
   public class IntentRole : IdentityRole
   {
        [MaxLength(200)]
        public string Group { get; set; }
        public int[] AccessLevel { get; set; }
   }
```

Validation for access levels:

```
   public static void ValidateACLValues(int[] accessLevel)
    {
        foreach (var access in accessLevel)
        {
            if (access <= 0)
            {
                throw new BadRequestException("Cannot set access level to a non-positive number!");
            }

            if (!Access.Any(a => a.AccessLevel.Equals(access)))
            {
                throw new NotFoundException($"Access level with value {access} has not been defined");
            }
        }
    }
```

[image]

This is the JSON that I have been sending:

```
{ "name": "test", "group": "test", "AccessLevel": [ 1,2,4 ] }
```

Comment: Can you post the json/xml that you post to this endpoint? My guess is that it contains a collection of strings, and you're trying to put it into a collection of numbers.

Comment: {
    "name": "test",
    "group": "test",
    "AccessLevel": [
      1,2,4
    ]
  }

Comment: What is `Delta<>`?

Comment: A class the tracks changes (i.e. the Delta) for an entity.

Comment: Is that the complete body of the request?

Comment: Yes. That is the complete body.

Comment: What happens if you change `AccessLevel` to be `public long[] AccessLevel { get; set; }`?

Comment: Or, for that matter, change it to `List<int>`?